# Getting WMS log messages in QGIS Noosa?

Tags: qgis

I work with QGIS 3.6.0 Noosa and closed the WMS-window in the log messages panel by accident (see image).

How can I get that window back?

[image: example that shows the log message window I'd like to get back, red circle]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question so that the relevant error message is in the question body as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

If you close a tab in the log panel, it will automatically reappear as soon as there will be a new request. So you have nothing to do, just wait and it will reappear.